# Scroll Menu not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a horizontal menu, that scrolls with the page, but it isn't seem to be working in IE.

```
// MAGIC HEADER
document.setscroll = false;
if(document.notbase) // If the document isn't a base.
{
    $(document).scroll(function()
    {
        if(window.scrollY >= 250 && !document.setscroll)
        {
            $("#bar").addClass("scroll");
            document.setscroll = true;
        }
        else if(window.scrollY < 250 && document.setscroll)
        {
            $("#bar").removeClass("scroll");
            document.setscroll = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working in IE.

Comment: share your HTML part or jsfiddle better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$(window).scroll
```

instead of

```
$(document).scroll
```